# cordova.js throwing error on its own callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

This recently just popped up in my Cordova app:

```
ErrorIn = https://myapp/cordova.js
ErrorAt = 314 : 13
Message = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
```

Line 314 (from the below function) is:

```
       cordova.fireWindowEvent('cordovacallbackerror', { message: msg, error: err });
```

Thats its...nothing else.  I am unable to trace it or determine whats causing this.  The only other thing I am able to determine is all the users it has happened to are on Android Samsung devices.

Cordova CLI 11.1.0
cordova-android: 11.0.0

Here is the function thats throwing the error:

```
/**
 * Called by native code when returning the result from an action.
 */
callbackFromNative: function (callbackId, isSuccess, status, args, keepCallback) {
    try {
        var callback = cordova.callbacks[callbackId];
        if (callback) {
            if (isSuccess && status === cordova.callbackStatus.OK) {
                callback.success && callback.success.apply(null, args);
            } else if (!isSuccess) {
                callback.fail && callback.fail.apply(null, args);
            }
            /*
            else
                Note, this case is intentionally not caught.
                this can happen if isSuccess is true, but callbackStatus is NO_RESULT
                which is used to remove a callback from the list without calling the callbacks
                typically keepCallback is false in this case
            */
            // Clear callback if not expecting any more results
            if (!keepCallback) {
                delete cordova.callbacks[callbackId];
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        var msg = 'Error in ' + (isSuccess ? 'Success' : 'Error') + ' callbackId: ' + callbackId + ' : ' + err;
       cordova.fireWindowEvent('cordovacallbackerror', { message: msg, error: err });  // ERROR HERE
        throw err;
    }
},
```

Any suggestions on how I can track this down?

Comment: is this the code from `cordova.js`? Seems you are looking at it in the wrong place. It may occur due to side effects. Share line no `314` in `cordova.js`

Comment: LINE 314 is listed in the function with `// ERROR HERE`

Comment: Can I have a full error stack?

Comment: Thats kind of the problem...that IS the only error.  I can't tell whats generating it or what is triggering it.  I mean, its `cordova.js` itself...if its not providing its own stack trace in the error reporting I don't know how to capture it.  Which is what I am asking for in this post.  My error reporting code does a stack trace....and thats all I am getting.